# What is the difference between WITH and ON in Doctrine Join condition type?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm searching for a better explanation about the difference between WITH and ON condition type for the doctrine clausure.

I'm finding the documentation about this very poor and I'm still in doubt.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In my opinion it's kind of a left over from doctrine 1.

Back then `ON` was used to redefine the join conditions of relations, whereas `WITH` was used to add more join conditions to the default one.

Now in doctrine 2 I have never seen a situation where `ON` can be used. In fact using `ON` always ends up in an exception saying you should use `WITH`.

Right now `WITH` can be used to add join conditions to the default one defined in a relation or, if no relation exists between two entities, define the join condition.

Comment: One of the most precise and simplest answers I heard on this topic.

Comment: One note - even if there is a relation, but only on the side being connected, not on the source entity => it behaves like there is no relation at all - so you have to add the `a.a_id=b.a_id` on your own :-)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see any answers here that made intuitive sense, so I re-read [the docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#on-keyword) a few times, had some back and forths with ChatGPT about it, and came away with this understanding:

#### `ON` in Join Condition

The `ON` keyword is used to specify a custom join condition that overrides the default automatic condition that Doctrine generates. You use `ON` to define how the tables are joined, similar to regular SQL, and this changes how the tables are matched together in that query.

For example:

```php
$queryBuilder
  ->select('a')
  ->from(Fruit::class, 'f')
  ->leftJoin(Aisle::class, 'a', 'ON', 'o.type = "produce"')
  ->where('f.name = "Pear"')
```

Should be equivalent to:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM fruit f
LEFT JOIN aisle a ON f.type = "produce"
WHERE f.name = "Pear";
```

#### `WITH` as Additional Filtering:

The `WITH` keyword is used to add custom filtering conditions to the join. It's used to filter the results of the join after the join condition has been applied. The conditions specified with `WITH` are appended to the automatically generated condition.

For example:

```php
$queryBuilder
  ->select('a')
  ->from(Fruit::class, 'f')
  ->leftJoin(Aisle::class, 'a', 'WITH', 'o.type = "produce"')
  ->where('f.name = "Pear"')
```

Should be equivalent to:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM fruit f
LEFT JOIN aisle a ON a.id = f.aisle_id AND f.type = "produce"
WHERE f.name = "Pear";
```

Comment: please note that the docs you reference here are Doctrine 1, but the question is about Doctrine 2. "ON" is still not supported even in Doctrine 4, see [github](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/ca8631c1728ee8106e625011217adf5f6f6514b8/src/Query/Parser.php#L1530)

Comment: @SBH What leads you to believe that the question is about Doctrine 2?

Comment: ok, fair enough its not mentioned. Historically, from context its was clearly the intention of the question asked, but I accept your point.
Edit: Stackoverflow blocks me from channing my vote on your answer until you edit it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ON` condition type requires having a relation between joined entities.
`WITH` can be used if no relation exists between entities, but we should satisfy some conditions using the other side of join.
In some contexts, where `ON` and `WITH` condition types are possible, I think that `ON` is interpreted faster and executed by almost DBMS.

Comment: "ON" is not supported at all in Doctrine 2, also not on entities with relations, see [github](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/ca8631c1728ee8106e625011217adf5f6f6514b8/src/Query/Parser.php#L1530)