# How to use conditionType 'ON' with Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-query

I have an issue with Doctrine concerning the condition `ON`. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101872/what-is-the-difference-between-with-and-on-in-doctrine-join-condition-type#answer-26103979) that:

> Now in doctrine 2 I have never seen a situation where ON can be used.
>   In fact using ON always ends up in an exception saying you should use
>   WITH.

But I need to redefine the join conditions. Here is my query:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('fu');
$qb
    ->addSelect('cra')
    ->innerJoin('fu.chatRoomAdmins', 'cra')
    ->where('cra.operator = :operatorId')
    ->setParameter('operatorId', $operatorId);
$foreignUsers = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And here is the (important part) generated sql query (I change the name of table to be more readable):

```
SELECT *
FROM   fu
       INNER JOIN cra
               ON fu.id = cra.operator_id
WHERE  ( cra.operator_id = 'an_id');
```

But I need to change the `ON` condition to this: `ON fu.id = cra.operator_id OR cra.operator_id IS NULL`

If I use the `WITH` condition like this :

```
$qb
//..
    ->innerJoin('fu.chatRoomAdmins', 'cra', 'WITH', 'cra.operator IS NULL')
//..
$foreignUsers = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

It changes my query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   fu
       INNER JOIN cra
               ON fu.id = cra.operator_id 
                  AND ( cra.operator_id IS NULL ) 
WHERE  ( cra.operator_id = 'an_id' );
```

But I want this `ON` condition : `ON fu.id = cra.operator_id OR ( cra.operator_id IS NULL )`

That why I tried to replace `WITH` by `ON` in my queryBuilder :

```
$qb
//..
    ->innerJoin('fu.chatRoomAdmins', 'cra', 'ON', 'cra.operator IS NULL')
//..
$foreignUsers = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But now I got an error : `Expected end of string, got 'ON'` (i'm using symfony 4)

Do you know a way to have this `ON` condition : `ON fu.id = cra.operator_id OR ( cra.operator_id IS NULL )` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it with `leftJoin` :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('fu');
$qb
    ->addSelect('cra')
    ->leftJoin('fu.chatRoomAdmins', 'cra')
    ->where('cra.operator = :operatorId OR cra.operator IS NULL');
$foreignUsers = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

which give this SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM   fu 
       LEFT JOIN cra
              ON fu.id = cra.operator_id 
WHERE  ( cra.operator_id = 'an_id' 
          OR cra.operator_id IS NULL );
```

Answer (score 0):

It works this way

```
$query->innerJoin('App\Domains\Order\Domain\Models\Order\B2bOrderExt', 'b2b', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'o.id=b2b.orderId');
```